# Php trying to insert a break line into a while statement

Tags: php

### Code

Look at the second echo under the second do

```
do {
    echo "<strong>Topic:". $row_AllTopics['topic'] . "</strong><br>";

    mysql_select_db($database_Select, $Select);
    $query_Comments = sprintf("SELECT * FROM comments where ((event_id=%s) AND (topic_id=%s)) ", $_POST['event_id'], $row_AllTopics['id']);
    $Comments = mysql_query($query_Comments, $Select) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_Comments = mysql_fetch_assoc($Comments);
    $totalRows_Comments = mysql_num_rows($Comments);

    do {
        // This is the echo in question.
        echo $row_Comments['comment'] . "Posted by: ". $row_Comments['poster'] . "\n";
    } while ($row_Comments = mysql_fetch_assoc($Comments));


} while ($row_AllTopics = mysql_fetch_assoc($AllTopics));
```

---

### Output

(This text is all centered align on the screen )

```
Topic:computer
linuxPosted by: andy linuxPosted by: andy Topic:computer
Posted by: Topic:ji
poPosted by: andy Topic:drive
makPosted by: andy Topic:new
nicePosted by: andy Topic:golf
holePosted by: andy plPosted by: andy
```

Comment: browsers expect html, view source and you would see line breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nl2br() function in PHP by:

```
echo nl2br($row_Comments['comment'] . "Posted by: ". $row_Comments['poster'] . "\n");
```

This will convert `\n` to `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\n`, try using `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

`"\n"` will cause a line-break in the source code. While Your browser will be rendering html so you need to use an HTML Line-Break ( `<br>` OR `<br />` ) Which will give the expected results.

So, Your code will be like this:

**BEFORE:** `echo $row_Comments['comment'] . "Posted by: ". $row_Comments['poster'] . "\n";`

**AFTER:** `echo $row_Comments['comment'] . "Posted by: ". $row_Comments['poster'] . "<br />";`